# Parse XML to JSON in Spring boot

Tags: java, json, xml

I've seen a couple of examples on how to do this. However, my XML structure doesn't look like the ones in the tutorials. I tried using the `DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();` but got stuck midways.

I've made a GET-request using:

```
URI url = "www.example.com";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
```

This is how it looks like (stripped down)

```
System.out.println(response);

<report>
  <fact label="started">2021-03-06 15:40:05.180</fact>
  <fact label="ended">2021-03-06 15:43:15.649</fact>
  <fact label="cases">47532</fact>
  <collection key="fail" label="Failed">
     <fact hash="4f3bc3837b5acdd1">bacon</fact>
     <fact hash="5f335409a07f9880">salami</fact>
     <fact hash="74706ca74c55e9bf">lemon</fact>
     <fact hash="14522f691d91d8bd">buttito</fact>
  </collection>
</report>
```

How can I parse this to JSON?

Comment: Use Jackson directly(not through Spring): https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-convert-xml-json

Comment: Yea, I am trying to follow that one, but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: My content is more nested, and not as predictable as the example on baeldung.

Comment: But you could use `JsonNode` from `xmlMapper.readTree` to map the values manually

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.xmlToJson(xml).